# Generic DI from interface not resolving in Startup

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, interface

I have created a generic interface

```
 public interface ISqlTradeDataRetriever<T> where T : class
{
    Task<T> GetSingleDayForSymbolAsync(string symbol, string date);

    Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllAsync(string symbol);        
}
```

and an implementation of such

```
 public class SqlCommodityDataRetriever: ISqlTradeDataRetriever<Commodity>
{
    private readonly BatlGroupWebContext _context;

    public SqlCommodityDataRetriever(BatlGroupWebContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    public Task<Commodity> GetSingleDayForSymbolAsync(string symbol, string date)
    {
        var data = _context.Commodities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Symbol == symbol
                                                                 && m.TradeDate == Convert.ToDateTime(date));

        return data;
    }

    public Task<ICollection<Commodity>> GetAllAsync(string symbol)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and in startup.cs of the web application

```
 services.AddScoped<ISqlTradeDataRetriever<Commodity>, SqlCommodityDataRetriever>();
```

but when I try to access the page where I am using this implementation I get an unresolved DI error

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Infrastructure.DataRetrievers.SqlCommodityDataRetriever' while attempting to activate 'BATLGroupApp.Pages.Commodity.TradeData.EditModel'.

The edit model is as follows

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SqlCommodityDataRetriever _retriever;

    public EditModel(SqlCommodityDataRetriever retriever)
    {
        _retriever = retriever;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public DomainClasses.Classes.Commodity Commodity { get; set; }
    public string CommoditySymbol { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync([FromQuery]string symbol, [FromQuery]string date)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(symbol) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        Commodity = await _retriever.GetSingleDayForSymbolAsync(symbol, date);
        if (Commodity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        CommoditySymbol = Commodity.CommoditySymbol.Symbol;

        return Page();
    }
 }
```

What am I doing wrong in terms of registering the DI for this OR is my implementation wrong?

Comment: You are registering against an interface but expecting the implementation is resolved when you ask for the implementation. That wont work. You'd have to register the implementation, `services.AddScoped<SqlCommodityDataRetriever>()`.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla...Totally correct, working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registration is fine in its current form.

```
services.AddScoped<ISqlTradeDataRetriever<Commodity>, SqlCommodityDataRetriever>();
```

The page model however expects the concrete `SqlCommodityDataRetriever` implementation while the container is only aware of its `ISqlTradeDataRetriever<Commodity>` abstraction.

Refactor the page model to match the registration

```
public class EditModel : PageModel {
    private readonly ISqlTradeDataRetriever<Commodity> _retriever;

    public EditModel(ISqlTradeDataRetriever<Commodity> retriever) {
        _retriever = retriever;
    }

    //... omitted for brevity since nothing else needs to change
```

as the class should ideally be dependent on abstractions instead of concretions for a more SOLID design.

Comment: ...@Wiktor Zychla comment worked as well, it appears that your answer is the most appropriate solution?

Comment: @dinotom Yes that comment directly addresses the cause of the error and provides a working solution. I am suggesting an alternative approach using common SOLID design practices. Both will work and ultimately the decision is yours which to use. The abstraction approach allows greater flexibility if the injected dependency needs to be mocked for isolated unit testing.